# label con display:inline coloca espacios entre

Tags: css

consulto sobre la propiedad display en un elemento label. Resulta que tengo un formulario donde los labels tienen las siguientes reglas:

```
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 0.98rem;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Los mismos se ven:

[image: resultado campos con display block]

Al querer colocar una clase (check) a un label para volver a la propiedad inline:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="acepto" name="acepto" value="si" />
            <label for="acepto" class="check"
              >Al enviar este formulario acepto la
              <span class="asterisco"
                >Política de privacidad de esta empresa</span
              ></label
            >
```

CSS:

```
.check {
  display: inline;
}
```

Logro colocar el label seguido al input (check) pero con mucho espacio entre las palabras:

[image: imagen de espacios]

¿Cómo puedo reducir ese espacio para que se vea un texto normal?

Comment: Lo acabe de probar y funciona bien, debe ser algún css adicional, o una class mal puesta. Te recomiendo inspeccionar elemento y tratarlo solucionar desde ahi

Comment: No te sale el texto con los espacios de la imagen?

Comment: No, copie y pegue y funciono bien